# Real time progress bar for JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, progress-bar

I was trying to show a real time progress bar for a large json data.

JSON file : https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbye7SetszftBAnq2QKQPTSye1nRp-bVU1Ymc-JKVa3WcHGUpI0H/exec

It takes around 7 second to load. I want to show some progress bar with real downloaded percentage.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbye7SetszftBAnq2QKQPTSye1nRp-bVU1Ymc-JKVa3WcHGUpI0H/exec',
    xhr: function() {
        console.log('xhr');
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener('loadend', uploadComplete, false);

        function uploadComplete(event) {
            console.log('uploadComplete');
            //do stuff
        }
        //Download progress
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
            console.log([evt.lengthComputable, evt.loaded, evt.total]);
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
                console.log(percentComplete + "p")
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("success")
    }
});
```

Output console :
[false, 32768, 0]
[false, 84414, 0]

`evt.lengthComputable` is coming as false and what does 32768 and 84414 mean? Why evt.total is showing as 0?

Is there any other way to show real time progress bar for a json data?

Answer (score -2):

```
$.ajax({
//..
  uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    console.log(percentComplete);
  }'
//..
});
```

then you can use 'percentComplete' variable to set width of progress bar or something else

Comment: this wont work without knowing (i,e. the server sending) the content length